# Method of Dynamically Accessing JSON Properties

Tags: json, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to dynamically access JSON properties for the purpose of updating the colors on my US map. It's ordinal data, and the set up is very simple:

```
var colorMap = {
'Outcome 1' : 'blue',
'Outcome 2' : 'lightblue',
'Outcome 3' : 'steelblue',
'None': 'gray'
}

var dataMap = {
'August' : d.properties.August,
'September' : d.properties.September,
'October' : d.properties.October
}

function update_colors(month) {
    svg.selectAll('path')
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            var data_entry = dataMap[month];
            if (data_entry) {
            return colorMap[data_entry];
            } else {
            return 'gray';
            }
        });
}
```

In the beginning I did simplify things by omitting the dictionary and using only the data of one JSON property:

```
var data_entry = d.properties.August;
```

In this case it worked fine, but it's not what I'm after, it's static. That's why I wanted to take it to the next step by creating a dictionary with the different properties. It doesn't work though, I get the error d is not defined for the first item in dataMap. I knew it wouldn't be defined in the true sense, but I thought it only NEEDED to be defined at the moment it was called, not initially too.

**My question is:** What do I need to change for the update_color function to work as expected? Feel free to scrap my approach in favor of something else, if you feel it is too feeble.

Note: Just for clarity, what the update_color function is supposed to do is take a string month value that is passed to it and use that to access the corresponding JSON property.

Comment: There's at least a couple issues with the code. Firstly dataMap is being defined as an object *before* d is defined (as you've noticed). Secondly, in your code you refer to "data_value" and this is not defined. There appears to be no relationship to color and month in your code?

Comment: That's a typo, let me fix that now. The relationship is supposed to be the update_colors function. I didn't include the part of the code that passes the string to it since that part is working correctly. It's also very simple, it's just an event listener that passes 1 of 3 strings (August, September, or October) to update_colors.